# Checking if the collection is empty in backbonejs

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am developing a one page application with requirejs and backbonejs which involves fetching of records from a db table and displays them. I am doing it on click of a button. I guess i am unnecessarily fetching the models from server repeatedly on click of a button.

What i want is that once i fetch the collection model on it should not fetch again on second click of the button. Any modifications/additions i do on collection are with server validations so i shall be able to keep the latest list without needing to fetch all the models again from the server on that button click.

So i need to check if the collection is empty or not before fetching the models. something like this:

```
if(window.invoices.isEmpty())
            {
                window.invoices.fetch({success:function(model){
                model.each(self.addOne,self);
                }});
            }
            else
            {
                window.invoices.each(self.addOne,self);
            }
```

Please shed some light if am going fundamentally wrong here.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `length` method.

`window.invoices.length == 0`

---

However I am a bit unsure what you are trying to do with `model.each(self.addOne, self)` . When you fetch a collection, Backbone will create the models from the returned JSON and populate the collection for you.

Comment: this code adds rows in the table. can isEmpty() function be used for the purpose?

Comment: isEmpty can be used too but that's an underscore method while length is a collection method. It might be underneath backbone is using isEmpty() but I think `window.invoices.length == 0` is far better than `_.isEmpty(window.invoice.length)`